# When is the Sturm-Liouville operator $ Lf=x^2f''+xf'$ positive

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

On the interval $[a,b]$

what conditions make the operator $L= (x^2)D^2 + xD$ positive?

here $D$ is the differentiation operator.

Comment: Do you want to include $0$ in the interval $[a,b]$ or not?

Comment: I don't need [a,b] to be in the interval

Comment: I don't know what your statement means?